# Reading integers from a file in C++

Tags: c++

A file contains the following data:

```
10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
```

I have read the first line into an integer array. Now I want to read the second line of numbers into a second array. How can I accomplish the second array thing?
I've used the following code to read in the first line:

```
while(!mystream.eof())
{
    mystream>>a[i];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: 10 11...15 is in one line..the rest in the other line!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverFlow! Please provide us with code to show us what you have tried so far and tell us where the problem is occurring so we can help you.

Comment: How did you read the first line? What does your code look like? Try doing the same thing for the second line.

Comment: I recommend you add code.

Comment: while(!mystream.eof())
 {
  mystream>>a[i];
  cout<<a[i]<<endl;
  i++;
 }

Comment: Sorry if i'm not clear..this is my first time here!

Comment: @AshwinRao Using `eof` to terminate a loop [is almost always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/509868); your case is no exception - replace your buggy code by one suggested in answers.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't included any code, I guess you just need a hint. So I will show some ways you can achieve this. Feel free to ask for more details and add code.

You can read every line in a `std::string` and parse it. You can choose between multiple parsing options, like knowing the string format (2 digit numbers followed by a space) and using something like `v[i] = (str[a] - '0') * 10 + str[a + 1] - '0';` (you need to figure what is the value of a for the i-th integer), or you can use a combination of `string::find` to search for spaces and `string::substr` to split it and something like `itoa()` to obtain an integer. Or, you can use `sscanf()`, even if it is a C function, to parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by reading a line of text into a `std::string` using `std::getline`.

I'd then initialize a `std::istringstream` from that string, and parse individual `int`s from that line and put them into a `std::vector<int>`. I'd probably do this using `std::istream_iterator<int>`s, and initialize the vector from a pair of them.

I'd repeat that process as long as `std::getline` succeeded.